# Find the formula for $w_k = w_{k-2} + k$ with $w_1 = 1, w_2 = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I'll try out several $w_k:$

$w_1 = 1$

$w_2 = 2$

$w_3 = 1 + 3$

$w_4 = 2 + 4$

$w_5 = (1 + 3) + 5$

$w_6 = (2 + 4) + 6$

It looks like when $n$ is even

$w_n = 2(1 + 2 + 3 + … + \frac k2) =  2(\frac {\frac k2 (\frac k2 + 1)}{2}) = \frac k2(\frac k2 + 1)$

How do we find the formula for when $n$ is odd? The sum of the first $k$ odd number is $k^2$, but that doesn't seem to help. What else can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have

$w_{2k}=w_{2k-2}+2k$
$w_{2k-2}=w_{2k-4}+(2k-2)$

.

.

.

$w_4=w_2+4$

by addition, we obtain

$\color{red}{w_{2k}=2+4+...(2k)=k(k+1)}$.

on the other hand

$w_{2k+1}=w_{2k-1}+(2k+1)$

.

.

.

$w_3=w_1+3$

so

$\color{red}{w_{2k+1}=1+3+5+...(2k+1)=(k+1)^2}$